# CSS background images en WordPress

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, wordpress

quería saber como vinculan background-image en CSS en wordpress, se que en el index a las imágenes se le agrega este codigo: php bloginfo('template_url') para los background-image es lo mismo? gracias!

php bloginfo('template_url'); ???

Comment: No es muy clara la pregunta, que es lo querés lograr? En wordpress hay funciones específicas para obtener la uri de una imagen del media library. Y hay una forma específica (funciones y hooks) para "encolar" los archivos css de estilos relacionados un post, template, pagina, etc.

Comment: Hola Juan, estoy haciendo una prueba con wordpress para hacer templates personalizados y resulta que en el css en una clase tengo una imagen de fondo que no me la esta tomando, quería saber como se incluye código php para que me tomes esa imagen-

Answer (score 1):

Para determinar la url de la imagen:

Si es una imagen que agregas vos en una carpeta dentro del theme. Podés usar [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) que deberia apuntar a la raíz de tu tema donde está el style.css y de ahí construis la ruta a la imagen.

Si la imagen está en el media Library podés o tomar la url directamente si sabes que no va a cambiar, o hacer alrtilugios como, independientemente del nombre, setearle un slug específico, y luego buscar la imagen usando el slug.

```
function get_attachment_url_by_slug( $slug ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'name' => sanitize_title($slug),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
  );
  $_post_imagen = get_posts( $args );
  $post_imagen = $_post_imagen ? array_pop($_post_imagen) : null;
  return $post_imagen ? wp_get_attachment_url($post_imagen->ID) : '';
}
```

[wp_get_attachment_url($post_imagen->ID)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

[Ref. a pregunta en SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115326/get-attachment-by-slug)

Yendo al css.

Si el css lo estás seteando como atributo style de un elemento en el html con recuperar la url de la imagen con alguno de los metodos anteriores, ya estarías. No habría mucha mas complejidad.

**EDITADO I**

```
<?php
$estilo = 'background-image: url(\'' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/serrucho-2.jpg\')';
?>
<div style="<?php echo esc_attr($estilo); ?>"></div>
```

Si el css está en su propio archivo .css, entonces no creo que lo puedas hacer on PHP. Sí lo podés hacer con un script por ejemplo usando jQuery.

El script lee la url de la imagen de una variable seteada con [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script), y la asigna al css de la clase que necesitás con una función de jQuery.

El script en sí, lo agregás en una carpeta dentro del theme, y lo bajas a la página con [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) cuando el request es para ese template en que estás trabajando.

Nota importante: Cualquier modificación a un theme, asumo que la hacés en un child-theme para no perder los cambios ante una actualización.

Comment: claro yo tengo la imagen en una carpeta img y en estilo que lo tendría que detallar asi? background-image: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/serrucho-2.jpg') ;

Comment: Fijate donde dice editado I

Comment: osea que <?php
$estilo = 'background-image: url(\'' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/serrucho-2.jpg\')';
?> lo tengo que poner en mi estilo?

Comment: osea que <?php
$estilo = 'background-image: url(\'' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/serrucho-2.jpg\')';
?> lo tengo que poner en mi estilo? no me queda claro en mi hoja de estilo como lo tengo que poner para vincular mi imagen. Yo tengo un div con la class borde y en mi estilo tengo .borde background-image y agregaria eso?

Comment: Si tenes una hoja de estilos aparte, no te sirve esa alternativa, tenes que hacer lo que está mas abajo en la respuesta. Donde dice "Si el css está en su propio archivo ..." No lo podés resolver con php". Basicamente el seteo lo hace cuando la página ya bajó con javascript / jQuery.